Quartus: too long compilation time problem - Stratix 10
I have a big design the suffering from very long compilation times,
The time is about 7hours to 8hours.
I would like to know if its normal according to the following details:
FPGA Device: Intel Stratix 10 - 1sm21beu2f55e1vg
Major Interfaces:
x4 E-Tile Ethernet Hard IP - 100G
PCIe
Interlaken Interface
Resources Used:
Logic utilization: 592905 / 702720 (84%)
Total block memory bits: 69%
Total RAM blocks: 6012 / 6847 (88%)
We also have timing issue; we usually get on our worst path slack of -400 - -500ps
Most of the logic runs on 415MHz clock, which is the o_clk_pll_div64 that coming from our E-Tile Ethernet Hard IP.
We are using ALOT of internal RAM for our calculation and search algorithms, that its problematic to move out of the FPGA (DDR4 is not an option right now, because we need 1/2 clocks feedback from our memories).
I heard suggestion that too-slow compilation time may occur because of wrong RAM instantiations, someone can elaborate about this? how to validate correct RAM instantiations.
We trying to optimize our RAM usage with smart usage of intel's M20K.
Any leads?
Thanks

How long is "too long"? Long compilation + timing errors usually means the fitter is having to work extra hard to meet timing due to tight constraints (high clock frequency, long combination paths etc).

For comparison we have a nearly full Arria 10 device (about a quarter of the resources you are using) which takes ~4 hours to compile [meeting timing], which is realistically perfectly normal. That's on a 12 core 3.5GHz Xeon CPU. Doing the same on a 24 core 4.5GHz Threadripper takes about 2.5 hours. So for yours anything under 6-7 hours is probably "normal" compile times.

sorry I forget to specify the time, I edited my post, its 7hrs to 8 hrs. we also using Xeon CPU with 32 cores (4th generation) and 512GB RAM

Have a look at some of the failing timing paths and see if there are any excessive routing delays (typically means lots of routing to meet hold timing was added). Any really long paths see if you can add pipelining.
